# Agile Environment/Teams

Tags: agile

I am trying to understand the concept of Agile. I have been reading up on Agile methodologies but keep seeing terms like Agile environment, and Agile Teams.

I thought Agile was just a methodology, but I'm not sure what is an agile environment and that agile teams actually exist!?

Comment: Agile is a mindset, a way of thinking about the work (see the agile manifesto). Scrum is an agile methodology, as is XP, as is Kanban etc...  Read Mike Cohn's Succeeding with Agile book.

Comment: Mike Cohn's book is suggested for users experienced with Agile. Any good beginner books?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, rather a development methodology.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary of agile methodologies is not wasted the time with a bureaucracy process of the steps of a life cycle. Instead of a long process the agile methodologies are more flexible and they focus on the code.

Nowadays more software companies join to the agile methodogy because they can be more efficient.

You can find more information about the practices, here:

[List of agile best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078688/list-of-agile-best-practices?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Think of Agile environment as the frame of a puzzle: you are given the framework and there are plenty of pieces able to be used in order to achieve your goal! Not necessarily all the pieces are to be used...
Agile Team is usually a team working in an Agile environment. Different methodologies (XP, Scrum etc) define different types of teams, of different sizes (project dependent) and so on.
The easiest way to understand Agile is to see it as the most flexible environment in which YOU need to self-organize and assume responsibility for your acts.
Once you start practicing agility in a business, especially if you have a good guide, you won't give it up ever - 'practice' is here the key word!

Answer (score 1):

Agile is an approach to development that follows certain principles, such as responding to change over following a plan.

An agile team is one that is following the agile approach to development.

An agile environment is one where many people are following the agile approach to development and as a result the environment reflects that approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking not just personally for you but for introducing Agile in your team or a company, you may find this interview useful: http://goo.gl/qYDjR3

This is a Q&A with the founder of Targetprocess who started to apply the Agile methodology in 2004 and who describes the stages Targetprocess went through, how they instil an Agile culture and enable self-organizing teams, trust and obsession with learning in software development teams.

Answer (score 0):

Agile is a methodology that grew from the [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/). Everyone seems to have a different approach or theory about Agile and new buzz terms keep springing up. I have always found in companies that I work for that Agile is great in theory, but bad in practice. It gets confusing very quickly and when it isn't successful, people will just say that you are doing it wrong. What you need is a methodology that learns from Agile but doesn't include it's limitations. Digital Animal have established a methodology that they use that does just this, they wrote an article explaining it here: http://digitalanimal.com/blog/slaying-the-agile-dragon-the-game-of-thrones-methodology/